# VNC server error

Tags: vnc

I am trying 2 connect to my raspberry pi and I have some troubles with my VNC server. I have signed in, turned on VNC on my raspberry pi and clicked to connect on my PC; however, I still receive this error:

[image]

I wonder if anyone help...

Comment: please ask a question about the error ... include the error text in your post .... do you think that if anybody googles `vnc server is not currently listening for cloud connections`, then they will find your question and the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is sort of open-ended, but these are some troubleshooting steps I can think of:

- Do you see the vnc service running on the pi  (`ps -ef | grep vnc`) ? If not, use `sudo raspi-config` to turn it on.
- Can your PC reach the pi by network?  (Can you ping the pi?)
- Can you ssh to the pi?  (Use `sudo raspi-config` to turn it SSH on to test this).
- Can you vnc to the pi from another machine (perhaps including using that pi itself, though that wouldn't make sense for use, just a connectivity test)
- Do you have the linux firewall on?  Perhaps take a look at `ufw` and [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1239154/how-can-i-configure-ufw-to-allow-vnc-access-to-my-computer-from-a-specific-ip-ad)

I suspect you are not making an outbound connection from the pi to the PC, but that's another option.

Also, there are times I prefer `tightvnc` over the default vnc service.  Perhaps trying that may uncover an issue stopping the built-in vnc.